# Telerik Grid eventType ClientEvents

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

How can i  attach handler for Grid ClientEvent in jquery? For example:

```
$('#Grid').data('tGrid')
.bind('OnDataBound', function () 
{ 
 // do somethihg with $(this)
})
```

But not:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBount(myFunc))
```

What's eventType of OnDataBound event?
 Thanks. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The "on" prefix is used only when the grid is created (i.e. server-side configuration or client-side initialization). To attach a handler dynamically, you should have a more jQuery-like approach:

```
$('#Grid').bind('dataBound', function () { 
    // do somethihg with $(this)
})
```